# System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality file size changing strangely

Tags: c#

I am trying out working with images and i came up to some strange behavior when using `Encoder.Quality`

I am having code like this:

```
try
{
    Image myImage = Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream());

    string final = "";

    MemoryStream ts = new MemoryStream();
    SaveJpeg(ts, myImage, 100);
    final += (ts.Capacity * 0.0009765625).ToString("0") + ", ";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        MemoryStream testStream = new MemoryStream();
        SaveJpeg(testStream, myImage, i * 10);
        final += (testStream.Capacity * 0.0009765625).ToString("0") + ", ";
    }
    return Json(final);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return View("Error", ex.ToString());
}




public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img, int quality)
{
    if (quality < 0)
        quality = 0;
    if (quality > 100)
        quality = 100;

    // Encoder parameter for image quality 
    EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
    // JPEG image codec 
    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
    EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
    img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
}
public static void SaveJpeg(Stream stream, Image img, int quality)
{
    if (quality < 0)
        quality = 0;
    if (quality > 100)
        quality = 100;

    // Encoder parameter for image quality 
    EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
    // JPEG image codec 
    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
    EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
    img.Save(stream, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
}

/// <summary> 
/// Returns the image codec with the given mime type 
/// </summary> 
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
{
    // Get image codecs for all image formats 
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    // Find the correct image codec 
    for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
        if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
            return codecs[i];

    return null;
}
```

It is asp.net core but i think that dosn't matter.

What matters here is that file i upload is "jpg" and it's size is `201kb` but output from this code is `512, 29, 41, 53, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 256, 512,`  (first number is quality 100, others are 0, 10, 20... 100)

When i store it into `MemoryStream` without changing quality i get same file size as my file.

Here i have two questions.

- Is quality level 90-100 somehow "enchancing" image quality?
- Why is image size from level 40-90 all same size, does it make any difference?

Comment: I think you should use `MemoryStream.Length` property instead of `MemoryStream.Capacity`.

Comment: Capacity is the underlying size of the internal buffer used, not the size of the data in question. This is so the MemoryStream can grow without causing excessive allocations

Comment: Oh.... Then question is not really valid since i haven't noticed i tested "capacity" and forgot to turn it back to length. With `length` it is working for second question but for first one `Is quality level 90-100 somehow "enchancing" image quality?` it  still is the same.